# Create multiple instance of app in Electron

Tags: javascript, github, cross-browser, cross-platform, electron

I have searched everywhere, but I couldn't find how to create multiple instance of my electron app. I am trying to create a **sticky note** app in which there is a plus window which is suppose to create a new sticky note which in turn will have that same plus button.

[image]

I have tried this but there is a huge problem on first time clicking plus button on sticky note a new instance is created but on second time clicking plus button 2 new instance are created and on the third time clicking plus button 4 new instance are created

> Inside main.js file

```
let mainWindow

function createWindow () {
  // Create the browser window.
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: 190, height: 190,frame:false,transparent:true})

  mainWindow.loadURL(url.format({
    pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'),
    protocol: 'file:',
    slashes: true
  }))
  mainWindow.on('closed', function () {
    mainWindow = null
  })
  //when plus button is clicked it is firing a message 'create-new-instance' through ipcRenderer
  ipcMain.on('create-new-instance',()=>{
    console.log('create new window');
    createWindow();
  })
}

//this is called when for the first time the app is launched
app.on('ready', createWindow)
```

> Inside renderer.js file where plus button is located

```
document.getElementById('plusButton').addEventListener("click", ()=>{
    var {ipcRenderer} = require('electron')
    ipcRenderer.send('create-new-instance')
})
```

The problem is when I first clicked plus button 'create-new-instance' is fired and as there is only one instance of note(created when you first start the app) a new note is created making it 2 instance of note both capable of listening to 'create-new-instance' event , when I second time clicked plus button both the notes listen to this event and create 1 note each making it total 4 notes .

please help me or suggest me any other alternate method how to do it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue here is that you're adding a listener for the `create-new-instance` event inside `createWindow()`, so every time `createWindow()` runs it adds another event listener, and when `create-new-instance` is emitted each of those listeners creates a new window. To avoid this you'll need to move the event subscription outside `createWindow()` so that there's only one listener for the event no matter how many times `createWindow()` is called.

Comment: that work, one more question each instance of an app is allocated 55MB of physical memory which is ok but if user opens 10 instance of app, it will add up to 500+MB of physical storage. Is there any alternative method that you know of to have an illusion that multiple instances of app is created but in-fact only one process is undergoing the hood